# C# windows forms charts

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу в visual studio 2022 создать форму с графиками данных.

Но в toolbox объект chart не активен

Что надо сделать?

Comment: Убедитесь, что версия фреймворка, под которую делаете приложение совпадает с диапазоном поддерживаемых дотнетов у установленного пакета с чартами. Ни данных о пакете, который вы используете, ни версии дотнета приложения, вы почему-то решили в этом вопросе не указывать.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания графиков можете воспользоваться готовым решением:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveCharts/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveCharts.Wpf/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveCharts.WinForms/

Видео на ютубе по взаимодействию, если не сможете разобраться самостоятельно:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbTnLihviq8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO3edHKFb68