# Как вывести точки построения в Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вывожу график построенный по массиву значений, который я уже высчитал. Как мне еще вывести точки, визуально?
Код вывода:

```
int[] x = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] f = new int[5] { -13, -14, 9, 68, 175 };
double a = x[0], b = x[4], h = 0.1, x1,y1;
chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
x1 = a;
while (x1<=b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
    {
        y1 = f[i];

        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x1, y1);
        x1 += h;
    }
}
```

Вот чтобы на этом графике появились точки x1 и y1.

[image: 1]

Comment: Не помню, чтоб в datapointcollection была такая возможность. Как вариант, можете воспользоваться готовыми решениями (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408200/c-windows-forms-charts/1408398#1408398). Точно помню, что в LiveCharts есть такая функция

Comment: Вот пример, как выглядит график, построенный с помощью LiveCharts - https://pastenow.ru/GXWBL. Тегните меня, если нужно будет объяснить, как пользоваться этим решением ("@Frehzy ...")

Comment: @Frehzy, а как с ним работать? Ну, я его добавил в VS вывел на форму. А каким образом мне еще вывести все то, что я до этого выводил...(

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Как повторить старые графики на новых? Есть методы AxisX.Add(new Axis...) для добавления оси Х и Series.Add(new LineSeries() ...) для добавления информации на графики для оси Y. С помощью этих методов добавляете нужную информацию

Comment: @Frehzy Слишком сложно для меня решение проблем с LiveCharts. Включил смекалку и в `Chart` добавил еще одну `Series` коллекцию=Point и повторил вывод с самим графиком. В итоге получилось то, что я и хотел)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте свойство:

```
chart.Series[0].ToolTip = "X = #VALX, Y = #VALY";
```

При наведении на график должны появиться значения точек.